# No Such Method Error on Rest Service at even though APACHE CXF 2.7.18 in POM.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf

this is the error I am getting, 
I have a Maven Projet that will consume other glasshish rest api but this error occurs.

I am using Apache Tomcat, Spring ,Hibernate and Ubuntu

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;] with root cause

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.setCommonProviders(ProviderFactory.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.setProviders(ClientProviderFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ClientProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.createInstance(ClientProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.initClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.initTargetClientIfNeeded(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.request(ClientImpl.java:238)
```

Here are the relevant sections of POM.xml

```
<cxf-bundle-jaxrs.version>2.7.18</cxf-bundle-jaxrs.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-bundle-jaxrs.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You should probably include the relevant sections of your pom.xml as well

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke, Here you go

Comment: Okay, I suspected a scope problem, but that's unlikely judging by your pom snippet.

Comment: This version is no longer supported, you should consider using 3.1.14 or 3.2.2.